# How does mounting (or unmounting) a partition affect the performance of the system?

Tags: mount, performance, unmount

Just curious to know: **how does mounting (or unmounting) a partition affect the performance of the system?**

I have a fairly large partition where have stored backups, software and old files that I don't need to access unless I rarely happen to. But I have set this partition to auto-mount at start-up along with other partitions. I just wanted to know if keeping this partition unmounted would save some resources in some way.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, keeping it mounted or unmounted should have negligible if any affect on your system's performance.  I have a 2 TB external that stays mounted all the time and I haven't noticed any ill effects on my system.  I just have it set to spin down when it's not being accessed so it doesn't wear out.  Now if you have search software set to index that drive and things of that nature, then yeah it might have an effect on those services, but overall I don' think it would hurt anything to leave it mounted.

Comment: Thanks, Gerowen. What you say makes sense. Thanks again.